# tcolorbox: Undefined control sequence \tcbsetmanagedlayer

Tags: tcolorbox

I don't know why, but I'm trying to change the `\tcbsetmanagedlayer` defined in `tcolorbox` in order to increase the number of maximal nested boxes. However, this fail with the error

> Undefined control sequence \tcbsetmanagedlayer

I pay attention to put it in the preamble, as stated by the documentation, so I don't understand what I missed. Any idea?

Thank you!

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetmanagedlayer{5}

\begin{document}%
Hello 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\tcbsetmanagerlayer` is a documentation typo `tcolorbox.pdf`.

The macro is called `\tcbsetmanagedlayers`, not `\tcbsetmanagedlayer`, note the `s` indicating a plural here.

Looking into the source file of `tcolorbox.sty` reveals this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetmanagedlayers{5}

\begin{document}%
Hello 
\end{document}
```

I have reported this issue here: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/32

Comment: Yes, this is a documentation typo. I will correct this for the next version.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: Thanks for your quick answer!